# Regex after a word, but not onto the new line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a comments filed.

General structure is:

```
hello: asdfasdfa
trace: Abacax number to
Part Number: ehool 
tap: 8765
```

I want to grab after trace: but nothing to do with part number.
So: "Abacax number to"

I am using this to grab after trade:

```
trace:\s*([^.]+|\S+)
```

But I can't figure out how to end the regex match when there is a new line?

Comment: `trace:[^\S\r\n]*(.+)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A potential way to do this is:

```py
import re

text = """
hello: asdfasdfa
trace: Abacax number to
Part Number: ehool 
tap: 8765
"""

match = re.search(r"trace: ?([^\r\n]*)", text)
print(match.group(1))
```

That will output `Abacax number to`

- `?` matches a space or nothing. So if the line is `trace:Abacax number to` it will still work.
- `([^\r\n]*)` captures and matches characters until a new line is detected. This is the first capture, so it will be group 1.

The regex also works if the trace line is the final line.